# Flutter - type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Tags: flutter, dart, exception

I am using `mysql1: ^0.19.2` and trying to fetch some data from a database to display in a select_form_field (`select_form_field: "^2.2.0"`). The database table I'm fetching data from contains 2 columns: 'id' and 'name' that should go as the `value` and `label` respectively in the `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` that fills the select_form_field.

I've created a method in my **database.dart** that fetches the data, fills a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` and returns it. The signature of the `connect()`-method looks like this `Future<MySqlConnection> connect() async {...}`:

```
getData() async {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];
  dynamic conn = await connect();

  var results = conn.query('select * from data');

  for (var row in results) {
    items.add({'value': row[0], 'label': row[1]});
  }

  return items;
}
```

In my **main.dart** I want to initialize this List and feed it to my select_form_field:

```
class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _items = getData(); // <-- Exception happens here

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column( 
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: SelectFormField(
            controller: nameController,
            hintText: "...",
            items: _items, // <-- List goes here
          ...
}
```

I've tried adding helper methods without an `async` signature from which I could initialize the list, but that didn't work. Other solutions I've found on StackOverflow don't seem to suit my problem.

Comment: can you add the code snippet of the "SelectFormField"?

Comment: @suzan Should be in the bottom code snippet. I excluded 'decoration' to make it easier to view. That package comes from here: https://pub.dev/packages/select_form_field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the data to get from an async function.
For example,

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _items = getData();
```

should be

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _items = await getData();
```

So final code should be

```
late List<Map<String, dynamic>> _items;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _getData();
}

_getData() async {
  _items = await getData();
}
```

Comment: While that makes sense, I can't make it work either. I added some more code to the second snippet that can hopefully explain better how I've set things up. I can't call await as it is just a variable of my MyCustomFormState class. I tried initializing and returning the list in a helper method with async signature and then calling this method as my items in select_form_field, but that gives the same exception as I started with.

Comment: for that, you should set the items in the initState function. I have added more snippet in the answer

Comment: With these changes I get this error: `LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_items@21190616' has not been initialized.)`. I tried adding `return _items;` to `_getData()` as well, but that gives me the original error. Do I call `_items` in the SelectFormField's `items:` or do I call `initState()` in some way?

Sorry for the many questions, I am just starting with Flutter.

Comment: I got a very similar error: Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<PopupMenuEntry<dynamic>>'
Did anyone solve this yet please?